# Kernel panic at 00000000 (wake_up_interruptible_all function)

Tags: c, linux, arm, kernel

I'm trying to get my rk3066 device to work using kernel source from https://github.com/bq/edison-2 and toolchain (gcc 4.6) from http://www.haoyuelectronics.com/service/RK3066/tools/linux/ . But device (rk3066 tablet - Tracer OVO 2.0) fails to boot with kernel panic message as described in title. I've also noticed that it is caused by line in rk30_lcdc.c:

```
static irqreturn_t rk30_lcdc_isr(int irq, void *dev_id)
{
    struct rk30_lcdc_device *lcdc_dev = (struct rk30_lcdc_device *)dev_id;
    ktime_t timestamp = ktime_get();

    lcdc_msk_reg(lcdc_dev, INT_STATUS, m_FRM_START_INT_CLEAR, v_FRM_START_INT_CLEAR(1));
    //lcdc_cfg_done(lcdc_dev);
    //lcdc_msk_reg(lcdc_dev, INT_STATUS, m_LINE_FLAG_INT_CLEAR, v_LINE_FLAG_INT_CLEAR(1));

    if(lcdc_dev->driver.num_buf < 3)  //three buffer ,no need to wait for sync
    {
        spin_lock(&(lcdc_dev->driver.cpl_lock));
        complete(&(lcdc_dev->driver.frame_done));
        spin_unlock(&(lcdc_dev->driver.cpl_lock));
    }

    lcdc_dev->driver.vsync_info.timestamp = timestamp;
    wake_up_interruptible_all(&lcdc_dev->driver.vsync_info.wait); //THIS LINE CAUSES KERNEL PANIC

return IRQ_HANDLED;
}
```

rk30_lcdc_device type:

```
struct rk30_lcdc_device{
int id;
struct rk_lcdc_device_driver driver;
rk_screen *screen;

//LCDC_REG *preg;         // LCDC reg base address and backup reg 
    //LCDC_REG regbak;
    void __iomem *regs;
void *regsbak;      //back up reg
int __iomem *dsp_lut_addr_base;

void __iomem *reg_vir_base;     // virtual basic address of lcdc register
u32 reg_phy_base;           // physical basic address of lcdc register
u32 len;                    // physical map length of lcdc register
spinlock_t  reg_lock;       //one time only one process allowed to config the register
bool clk_on;            //if aclk or hclk is closed ,acess to register is not allowed
u8 atv_layer_cnt;       //active layer counter,when  atv_layer_cnt = 0,disable lcdc

unsigned int        irq;

struct clk      *pd;                //lcdc power domain
struct clk      *hclk;              //lcdc AHP clk
struct clk      *dclk;              //lcdc dclk
struct clk      *aclk;              //lcdc share memory frequency
struct clk      *aclk_parent;       //lcdc aclk divider frequency source
struct clk      *aclk_ddr_lcdc;     //DDR LCDC AXI clock disable.
struct clk      *aclk_disp_matrix;  //DISPLAY matrix AXI clock disable.
struct clk      *hclk_cpu_display;  //CPU DISPLAY AHB bus clock disable.
struct clk      *pd_display;        // display power domain
u32 pixclock;
};
```

rk_lcdc_device_driver type:

```
struct rk_fb_vsync   vsync_info;
/* Cut here */
```

rk_fb_vsync type:

```
struct rk_fb_vsync {
wait_queue_head_t   wait;
ktime_t         timestamp;
bool            active;
bool                    irq_stop;
int         irq_refcount;
struct mutex        irq_lock;
struct task_struct  *thread;
};
```

I've tried commenting (buggy?) line, but in result screen shows no text in console mode on built-in screen (without Xserver). How to solve this or where to start finding solution ?

Best regards,

Tomasz Jeruzalski

Comment: Are you trying to use a null pointer inappropriately?

Comment: This code isn't created by me. It's a leak from Rockchip (thanks to BQ) and I don't know how to modify function rk30_lcdc_isr. I want to have text-mode console on my device and 3D acceleration in graphic mode (I didn't test it yet).Maybe this is nested structures-related problem ? Even when I commented that line or/and disabled all *vsync* functions in rk3066 drivers I get blank display.

Comment: `How to solve this or where to start finding solution?` - **Debug**. From "fatal error" message extract actual line which cause error, content of the registers at that moment. According to the PC register determine asm-line which cause an error, and determine register which is incorrect. Then track that register to C variable. And so on. These actions you should perform **on your machine**, Stack Overflow cannot help with that.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: could you give me link for tutorial of method you mentioned above ? Just to be sure that I'm doing it right way.

Comment: Your may start with [Bug hunting](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/bug-hunting.html) guide on kernel.org.

Comment: Look at users of `rk_fb_vsync` and the `wait` element.  What does `wake_up_interruptible_all` do?  It wakes up registered users.  If the a registers user is 'NULL' you will see what you have.  Did someone deallocate without deregistering?